# How do I reference a class in PHP?

Tags: php, class, codeigniter

I'm trying to do some PHP development but I can't figure out how to reference my class in another PHP file. I am using CI as my MVC framework and under 'Application' I have created a folder called, 'domain' where I am placing my domain specific objects.

I have a class called 'user' defined in a file called 'User.php'. So 'domain/User.php'

I am trying to reference this class in another PHP file like this:

```
<?php

require('domain/User.php');

..

?>
```

This blows up with this error:

> Failed opening required 'domain/User.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php')

So, clearly, I don't know how this is done in PHP. So can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: It just means it couldn't find the file. Either you've got the path wrong or the search path is wrong. It could also mean the permissions are wrong.

Comment: I guess the error message is what is throwing me off. It appears to be looking in my usre/lib/php location. I checked permissions and everyone has read access. CI must be rerouting the url maybe??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you're referencing the correct path.  If you're creating a new CI Controller (i.e. a controller that *extends* the core CI_Controller), you can easily solve this by using:

`include (APPPATH . 'domain/User.php');`

Otherwise, you can find the absolute path of the current file by using:

```
$current_path = dirname(__FILE__);
```

Allowing you to reference whatever external file you want relative to the current file you're using:

```
include ($current_path . '../domain/User.php');
```

You can then reference all your external controllers and methods without any trouble.  If you wanted to run function_a() in an external file, you'd need to use:

```
$this->user = new User();
$this->user->function_a();
```

You could put these loads into a `__construct` function to avoid repetition in your code.

Comment: Awesome.. I used dirname(__FILE__) to find out the current context. Turns out I was missing a leading '/'

Answer (score 0):

The file most likely does not exist (at the expected location).

First, you should figure out where the current file is located. To do that, use `echo __FILE__;` before the `require`. Then, make sure `domain/User.php` is actually available at the expected location.

If, however, your includes are located somewhere completely different, you should set up a proper `include_path` for PHP. You can do so by adjusting the setting in your `php.ini` file.